# Como fazer verificação de um State pra saber se ele é undefinied em react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou usando o react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker como datePicker em um app, fiz um tratamento pra quando apertassem o cancelar na hora da seleção do datepicker, o valor de date não ficasse undefined, mas fica dando esse warning a cada vez que aperto em cancelar, não sei se fiz o tratamento do setState corretamente.
O state date é pra vir por padrão como a data atual, quando acionado e selecionado o datepicker, deve mudar a data atual pra selecionada, senão continua com o mesmo valor.

**Erro**

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Invariant Violation: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.
http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:4607:37
setState@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:4610:11
setDate@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:118736:25
resolve@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:128849:19
tryCallOne@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:26986:16
http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27087:27
_callTimer@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30541:17
_callImmediatesPass@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30577:19
callImmediates@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30796:33
callImmediates@[native code]
__callImmediates@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2561:35
http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2338:34
__guard@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2544:15
flushedQueue@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2337:21
flushedQueue@[native code]
invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { TextInputMask } from 'react-native-masked-text';
import ReactoTron from 'reactotron-react-native';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

import moment from 'moment';
import Header from '~/components/Header';
// import ListItem from '~/components/ListItem';
import styles from './styles';
import { colors } from '~/styles';
import { data } from '~/components/Data';

AsyncStorage.clear();

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const thumbnailWidth = 90;
const columnCount = Math.floor(width / thumbnailWidth);
const gutter = (width - columnCount * thumbnailWidth) / (columnCount * 2);

export default class Events extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
navigation: PropTypes.shape({
  navigate: PropTypes.func,
}).isRequired,
  };

  static navigationOptions = {
title: 'Eventos',
tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="clock" size={20} color={tintColor} />,
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
swipeEnabled: true,
animationEnabled: true,
initialLayout: undefined,
  };

  // constructor(props) {
  //   super(props);
  //   this.state = {
  //     date: moment,
  //   };
  // }

  state = {
dt: '',
date: new Date(),
prevDate: '',
maxDate: new Date(),
mode: 'date',
show: false,
data: [
  {
    id: 0,
    type: 'cashier',
    color: colors.blue,
    icon: 'cash-register',
    title: data.caixa.title,
    subTitle: 'Saldo Final: R$300',
    datetime: '23/07 19:01',

    cashier: {
      user: data.caixa.cashier.user,
      fundCash: '100,00',
      dateInit: '23/07/2019',
      timeInit: '08:00',
      dateEnd: '23/07/2019',
      timeEnd: '19:01',
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$ 17,50 vendido por Administrador',
    subTitle: '1x Coca cola, 2x Cerveja brahma',
    datetime: '25/07 18:55',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Administrador',
      client: 'Fulano da Silva Sauro',
      detail: 'Vendeu 2 itens',
      total: 'R$ 17,50',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Coca-cola',
          amount: '1',
          price: '5,50',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '5,50',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          description: 'Cerveja brahma',
          amount: '1',
          price: '15,00',
          discount: '3,00',
          total: '12,00',
        },
      ],

      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '12,00',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          description: 'Cartão Débito',
          total: '5,50',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: '',
    color: colors.red,
    icon: 'archive',
    title: 'Acabou cerveja',
    subTitle: 'Fim estoque',
    datetime: '23/07 18:50',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$ 89,00 vendido por Administrador',
    subTitle: '10x Cerveja, 2x Redbull, 1x cachaça',
    datetime: '23/07 18:50',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Administrador',
      client: 'Ana Baiana Meleva Daqui Pratinhos',
      detail: 'Vendeu 3 itens',
      total: 'R$ 89,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Cerveja Skoll',
          amount: '10',
          price: '5,50',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '55,00',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          description: 'Redbull',
          amount: '2',
          price: '12,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '24,00',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          description: 'Cachaça 51',
          amount: '1',
          price: '10,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '10,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 2,
          description: 'Cartão Débito',
          total: '89,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 'productStock',
    color: colors.yellow,
    icon: 'archive',
    title: 'Cerveja acabando',
    subTitle: 'Estoque atual: 10',
    datetime: '23/07 18:40',
    productStock: {
      minStock: 10,
      maxStock: 30,
      stock: 20,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$2,00 vendido por Beltrano',
    subTitle: '1x Caixa Bombom Nestle',
    datetime: '23/07 18:30',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Beltrano',
      client: 'Não informado',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 5,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Caixa bombom Nestle',
          amount: '1',
          price: '5,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '5,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Cartão Débito',
          total: '5,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$2,00 vendido por Fulano',
    subTitle: '1x Pirulito',
    datetime: '23/07 18:00',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Fulano',
      client: 'Não informado',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 2,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Pirulito',
          amount: '1',
          price: '2,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '2,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '5,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$25,00 vendido por Fulano',
    subTitle: '1x Sorvete Kibom Chocolate',
    datetime: '23/07 17:20',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Fulano',
      client: 'Não informado',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 25,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Sorvete Kibom Chocolate',
          amount: '1',
          price: '25,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '25,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '25,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$15,00 vendido por Fulano',
    subTitle: '3x Bolacha Choc. Balduco',
    datetime: '23/07 15:00',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Fulano',
      client: 'Não informado',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 15,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Bolacha Choc. Balduco',
          amount: '3',
          price: '5,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '15,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '15,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$3,00 vendido por Beltrano',
    subTitle: '1x Chocolate Diamante Negro',
    datetime: '23/07 13:00',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Beltrano',
      client: 'Não informado',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 5,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Diamante Negro',
          amount: '1',
          price: '3,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '3,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '3,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$15,00 vendido por Fulano',
    subTitle: '1x Caixa de brinquedos',
    datetime: '23/07 12:10',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Fulano',
      client: 'Não informado',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 15,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Caixa de brinquedos',
          amount: '1',
          price: '15,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '15,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '15,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    type: '',
    color: colors.red,
    icon: 'archive',
    title: 'Acabou Caixa Bombom Garoto',
    subTitle: 'Fim estoque',
    datetime: '23/07 10:40',
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    type: 'sale',
    color: colors.green,
    icon: 'shopping-cart',
    title: 'R$5,00 vendido por Fulano',
    subTitle: '1x Caixa Bombom Garoto',
    datetime: '23/07 10:40',

    sale: {
      seller: 'Fulano',
      client: 'Amável Pinto',
      detail: 'Vendeu 1 item',
      total: 'R$ 5,00',

      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Caixa bombom Garoto',
          amount: '1',
          price: '5,00',
          discount: '0,00',
          total: '5,00',
        },
      ],
      payments: [
        {
          id: 1,
          description: 'Dinheiro',
          total: '5,00',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    type: 'productStock',
    color: colors.yellow,
    icon: 'archive',
    title: 'Caixa bombo Garoto acabando',
    subTitle: 'Estoque atual: 1',
    datetime: '23/07 10:20',
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    type: 'cashier',
    color: colors.blue,
    icon: 'cash-register',
    title: 'Caixa Aberto por Fulano',
    subTitle: 'Saldo Inicial: R$100',
    datetime: '23/07 07:00',

    cashier: {
      user: 'Administrador',
      fundCash: '100,00',
      dateInit: '23/07/2019',
      timeInit: '08:02',
      dateEnd: '',
      timeEnd: '',
    },
  },
],
  };

  // DatePicker functions

  // FIXME: ERROR ON CANCEL
  setDate = (event, date) => {
// this.prevDate = moment().format();
this.prevDate = moment().format();
date = date || this.date;

ReactoTron.log('prevdate state', this.prevDate);
ReactoTron.log('data state', this.date);
ReactoTron.log('datalocal', date);

if (date === undefined) {
  this.setState({
    date: this.prevDate,
  });
}

this.setState({
  show: Platform.OS === 'ios',
  date,
});

if (date !== undefined) {
  this.setState(this.prevDate = date);
}
  }

  show = (mode) => {
this.setState({
  show: true,
  mode,
});
  }

  datepicker = () => {
this.show('date');
  }

  renderEventItem = (item) => {
const { navigation } = this.props;

const { type } = item;

if (type === 'cashier') {
  navigation.navigate('Cashier', { item });
} else if (type === 'sale') {
  navigation.navigate('Sale', { item });
} else if (type === 'productStock') {
  navigation.navigate('ProductStock', { item });
}
  };

  onShowArrow = (item) => {
if (item.type !== '') return <Icon name="angle-right" size={15} color="#e0e0e0" style={styles.iconArrow} />;
return null;
  };

  formatDate() {
const { date } = this.state;
// if (date === undefined) {
//   date = moment().format();
// }

const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth();
const year = date.getFullYear();
return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
ReactoTron.log('FORMATDATE');
ReactoTron.log(`${day}/${month}/${year}`);
  }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  onPress={() => {
    this.renderEventItem(item);
  }}
>
  <View style={[styles.listItem, { borderLeftColor: item.color }]}>
    <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
      <Icon name={item.icon} color={item.color} size={25} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.centerContainer}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>{item.subTitle}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
      <View>
        {/* <Text style={styles.textHour}>{item.datetime.substring(5, 11)}</Text> */}
        <Text style={styles.textHour}>{item.datetime.substring(5, 11)}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>{this.onShowArrow(item)}</View>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );

  render() {
const {
  show, date, mode, dt, maxDate,
} = this.state;

return (
  <View>
    <Header title="Eventos" />
    <View style={styles.containerDate}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonCalend} onPress={this.datepicker}>
        <Image style={styles.btnIcon} source={require('../../images/date_icon.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.textDateFilter}>{this.formatDate()}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      { show && (
      <DateTimePicker
        value={date}
        mode={mode}
        maximumDate={maxDate}
        display="default"
        onChange={this.setDate}
        onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
      />
      )
    }
    </View>

    <FlatList
      style={styles.flatList}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: impossível verificar esse código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema tá descrito no próprio warning

> Invariant Violation: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.

Ou seja, você não está enviando um objeto ou uma função que retorne um objeto de estados. Isso ocorre em dois partes do seu código:

```
if (date === undefined) {
  this.setState(
    this.date = this.prevDate,
  );
}
```

...

```
if (date !== undefined) {
  this.setState(this.prevDate = date);
}
```

O correto, nesses casos, seria você preencher com um objeto, não com a atribuição. Fora isso, você não está trabalhando com os valores do `state`, para acessar um de seus valores deve ser feito `this.state.valorDesejado`. Por exemplo, no da data do estado, seria `this.state.date`. Já para corrigir o problema das atribuições, o correto seria:

```
if (date === undefined) {
  this.setState({
    date: this.state.prevDate,
  });
}
```

Isso deve resolver alguns dos teus problemas.

Comment: fazendo só essa alteração aparece um typeError:
______________________________________________                   
`WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): 
TypeError: date.getDate is not a function. (In 'date.getDate()', 'date.getDate' is
undefined)`

Comment: outro problema é que prevDate é uma string, não um `Date`, então ela não tem a função `getDate`

Comment: Troquei todos onde tem `this.date` ou `this.prevDate` adicionando `this.state`, antes dessa  alteração já funcionava, mas ficava dando aquele warning, agora está ok, só está dando uns problemas de eslint